# Uncaught Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined - Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, jquery, ajax

I get a valid geojson from the database using a query. Below one is the php script used to read the data.

```
<?php
include "../includes/init.php"; // including data base connection

$sql = "SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) AS geojson FROM feature_drawn";
// echo $sql;

$query = $pdo->query($sql); // query executing

$geojson = array(
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features' => array(),
);
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $feature = array
        (
        'type' => 'Feature',

        'geometry' => json_decode($row['geojson'], true),
        'properties' => array
        (
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'type' => $row['type'],
        ),
    );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}

echo json_encode($geojson);
```

Below shown the javascript code that use to get the geojson object

```
var load_features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'scripts/load_features.php',
    success: function(data, status) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  })
 );

var myview = new ol.View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  center: [80.98885377363007, 6.830454104603501], // remeber to set latlon in 'lon' first and 'lat' scecond
  zoom: 17
});

// OSM Layer
var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

// Draw vector layer
// 1. Define source
var draw_source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: load_features
})
// 2. Define layer
var draw_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: draw_source
})

// Layer Array
var layer_array = [baseLayer, draw_layer]

// Map
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'mymap',
  view: myview,
  layers: layer_array,
});
```

And here is what I get as a geojson object from `console.log(data); console.log(JSON.parse(data));`

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.988864502, 6.833924883]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfd",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.991310677, 6.833206051]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfddfd",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [80.989712081, 6.834246748],
          [80.991203389, 6.834182375],
          [80.990473828, 6.833334797],
          [80.989669165, 6.832712525],
          [80.990237793, 6.832100981]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfddfd",
        "type": "Roads"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [80.988113484, 6.833699578],
          [80.988971791, 6.83211171]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfddfd",
        "type": "Roads"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [80.987641415, 6.827981108],
            [80.9870406, 6.827015513],
            [80.987459025, 6.82657563],
            [80.988907418, 6.826725834],
            [80.987641415, 6.827981108]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfddfd",
        "type": "Buildings"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.988816223, 6.833892697]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "a",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.989459953, 6.832787626]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "ab",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.98782917, 6.830491656]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "abc",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.991745195, 6.83312022]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "abcd",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.989733538, 6.832605236]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "q",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.984444222, 6.830062502]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "s",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }]
  }
```

[image: Console screenshot]

I verified the geojson using [geojsonlint.com](https://geojsonlint.com/) and it showed every feature without any problem.

[image: geojsonlint.com screenshot]

But the problem is, in my map it does not show up. It shows this error on the console.

```
Uncaught Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined
    at i_ (ol.js:2)
    at n.readFeatureFromObject (ol.js:2)
    at n.readFeaturesFromObject (ol.js:2)
    at n.readFeatures (ol.js:2)
    at main.js:255
```

This is what included in `main.js` line `255`

[image: main.js line 255]

Then I tried removing `$.ajax` call within `readFeatures` and pasted the whole geojson object insode the `readFeatures()`

Below shown the change

```
var load_features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
   {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.988864502, 6.833924883]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfd",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.991310677, 6.833206051]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfddfd",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [80.989712081, 6.834246748],
          [80.991203389, 6.834182375],
          [80.990473828, 6.833334797],
          [80.989669165, 6.832712525],
          [80.990237793, 6.832100981]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfddfd",
        "type": "Roads"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [80.988113484, 6.833699578],
          [80.988971791, 6.83211171]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfddfd",
        "type": "Roads"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [80.987641415, 6.827981108],
            [80.9870406, 6.827015513],
            [80.987459025, 6.82657563],
            [80.988907418, 6.826725834],
            [80.987641415, 6.827981108]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "sdfdfsdfddfd",
        "type": "Buildings"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.988816223, 6.833892697]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "a",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.989459953, 6.832787626]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "ab",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.98782917, 6.830491656]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "abc",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.991745195, 6.83312022]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "abcd",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.989733538, 6.832605236]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "q",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [80.984444222, 6.830062502]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "s",
        "type": "Trees"
      }
    }]
  }
);
```

Then there is no error shown in the console and All the features are shown on the map.

[image]

I was looking for hour for a solution, and still I do not understand what is defined by `Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined`. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery `$.ajax` method does not return the data, but promise to fetch the data. This means you have to turn your GeoJSON data fetch inside out:

```
var load_features; 
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'scripts/load_features.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data, status) {
    load_features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data);
  }
});
```